# Create a map with composite key with Java 8 on the fly

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a map like below->

```
Map<Pair<MyClass.a, MyClass.b>, MyClass>>.
```

I have a list of object ->

```
List<MyClass>
```

Here Pair is a class, already in my project, so I wanted to use it.

I need help to create it from a Java 8 stream.

I did try ::

```
ls.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(new Pair(MyClass.a, MyClass.b), MyClass));
```

But I am getting an error. I am new to Java 8 and trying to learn it.

Adding an example :

```
class Person {
   String name ;
   int age ;
   // Some other variables
}
```

I have a list of `List<Person>`.

In my requirement I need a key = {name, age}, using the pair class.

```
class Pair<T,U> {     
    Pair(T t, U u) {
        this.t = t
        this.u = u
    }

    // Overridden hashCode && equals methods
}
```

Now I want to create a map like `Map<Pair<String, Int>, Person>`

I was getting a compiler error that said "Not a functional interface".

I am sure there must be a way via java 8 stream and collect.

Comment: What is `MyClass.a` and `MyClass.b`? Are they fields of `MyClass`? You may use only *classes* as the generics arguments, not fields. In other words, between the parenthesis `<..>` may be only *class* names, not *field* names.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in the result `Map`? Add an example to your question, like: "For input list ... I want to have the following resulting map: ..."

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? This is also not clear. Please reformulate your question in a more precise way.

Comment: @HonzaZidek, I just added a simple example .

Comment: How is defined `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your class? Is it dependent only (and exactly) on the two fields which you want to use for the key? And you have not fixed the other issues. I'm afraid you are trying to understand Java 8 features too prematurely :) Start with understanding the Java generics.

Answer (score 12):

In order to create a function, you must use a *lambda expression*. It’s not sufficient an write an expression like `new Pair(MyClass.a, MyClass.b)`, instead, you specify a function having a parameter, that will be a `Person` instance, i.e. `p -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age)`. Alternatively you may make the parameter explicit: `(Person p) -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age)`.

For your `Map` creation operation, you have to decide, what you want. E.g.,

```
Map<Pair<String, Integer>, List<Person>> map
    = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age)));
```

will map each key to a list of all `Person` instances having that name/age combination.

In contrast

```
Map<Pair<String, Integer>, Person> map
    = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age), p -> p));
```

will map the name/age pairs to a single `Person` instance, but throw an exception, if there is more than one with the same key. You can specify a function to resolve such conflicts, e.g.

```
Map<Pair<String, Integer>, Person> map = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(p -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age), p -> p, (first, next) -> first));
```

will keep the first, whereas

```
Map<Pair<String, Integer>, Person> map = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(p -> new Pair<>(p.name, p.age), p -> p, (prev, last) -> last));
```

will overwrite the previous occurrence, ending up with the last `Person` instance for each name/age combination.